# Win11 normal account with no wifi but SSH account with wifi

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, ssh, user-accounts

I'm trying to manage a machine, and would like no network access for the currently logged in account, but want to still manage the machine remotely through SSH and this will obviously requires being connected

In Windows 11, is it possible to have two accounts, one that is currently logged in but is not connected to any WiFi, while there is another account used solely for SSH, and is always connected to WiFi?

I'm open to other approaches

Edit: the account with no access is always logged in

Comment: One can limit WiFi access *per user* with GPO: https://thesysadminchannel.com/how-to-restrict-internet-access-using-group-policy-gpo/

Comment: If the machine has no network access then it cannot initiate a SSH connection. What you want isn’t possible.

Comment: That is obvious, but is it possible to have access for only the ssh account, while restricting access to the other account?